# XSLT: Sorting like SOLR

Tags: xml, xslt, sorting

I am using an XSLT to sort a piece of XML such as:

```
<feed>
   <entry>
      <title>A To Z</title>
   </entry>
   <entry>
      <title>Action</title>
   </entry>
</feed>
```

The XSLT looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
 xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

 <xsl:param name="name" select="'title'" />
 <xsl:param name="order" select="'ascending'" />

 <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

 <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="atom:feed">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="/atom:feed/*[not(self::atom:entry)]" />
   <xsl:apply-templates select="/atom:feed/atom:entry">
    <xsl:sort select="*[name() = $name]" order="{$order}" />
    <xsl:sort select="atom:id" data-type="number" />
   </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I expect the values to come out in an order such as A To Z, then Action, but the result contains the opposite. It would look like the whitespace is being ignored as a value to sort by.

Comment: @smokedice I removed some unused parameters and namespaces to make the XSLT easier to read. Comment or edit if you feel those are important to the question

Comment: @smokedice: Seems to work for me, how is it failing?

Comment: The problem is that the first title that is produced is Action, then followed by A to Z. @Lazarus did you use Xerces to apply the template?

Comment: I used the built-in engine in Altova XMLSpy, worked fine for me. I think @Nick Jones may have nailed it in his answer below.

Comment: @smokedice: I wouldn't use `name()` unless I'm sure whether the namespace is the default namespace or it was bound to a prefix. Also, do note that your input document doesn't have the Atom namespace declaration.

Comment: This is what I processed: http://pastebin.com/aefethTq and this is what I got http://pastebin.com/WQkmCSVg . I expected the two xml fragments to be the same.. I haven't a clue what version of the XSLT spec that Xerces uses. A quick google around doesn't return anything either :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XSLT 1.0 the sorting is implementation defined, so it is quite possible some implementations ignore space for sorting. Which implementation are you using?

I'd recommend something like:

`<xsl:sort select="translate(*[name() = $name],' ','_')" order="{$order}" />`

Might solve your problem (although again depends on how the implementation of XSLT you are using sorts '_')

Comment: I cannot really add in _'s into the data. Once the XML is sorted it is then compared to the original to see if the data was sorted.

Comment: This won't add _ into the data, only into the sort key generated for sorting the data.

Answer (score 1):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:param name="name" select="'title'" />
    <xsl:param name="order" select="'ascending'" />
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="atom:feed">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::atom:entry)]" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="atom:entry">
                <xsl:sort select="*[local-name() = $name]" order="{$order}" />
                <xsl:sort select="atom:id" data-type="number" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With this input (**with namespace declaration**):

```
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <entry>
        <title>A To Z</title>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <title>Action</title>
    </entry>
</feed>
```

Output:

```
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <entry>
        <title>A To Z</title>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <title>Action</title>
    </entry>
</feed>
```

Tested with MSXSL 3/4, Saxon, Altova, XQSharp. **Note**: Only Oracle, **and Xalan** sort 'Action' before 'A To Z' in ascending order.

Comment: Hi Alejandro. Xerces outputted the data in the wrong order when using your xslt: pastebin.com/aefethTq pastebin.com/WQkmCSVg . Any ideas?